# React & HTML: Highlight a table cell with booleans

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I'm using React, and was wondering wether it is possible to highlight a table cell with a boolean, kind of this here:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td {if (highlight)  bgColor = 'red'} >Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Where highlight is a boolean state variable).

Comment: Yes, you can use ternary operator to add inline style or class based on condition, preferred to use class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can. Simply use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?retiredLocale=vi) for that:**

```
<td style={{backgroundColor: highlight ? 'red' : ''}} >Emil</td>
```

Comment: You could mark this as accept if it helps and for others who need it.